# Using an adjective as a noun

Tags: adjectives, nominalization

When a word (for example 'transgender') is classified by a dictionary (for example Merriam-Webster) just as adjective and not as noun, how bad is it to use it as a noun?

Does this sentence fragment make sense?

> Discrimination of transgenders...

or

> ...transgenders were...

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/305305/216106 for information about [nominalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization).

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense (except that I would say "discrimination against" rather than "discrimination of").

This sort of nominalisation quite often occurs and is easy to understand.

However, you have to be a bit careful.  Referring to (for example) "gays" or "blacks" can come across as offensive.  The preferred usage is adjectival ("gay people", "black people").

From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gay):

> *gay*  noun 10. *Sometimes Offensive.* a homosexual person, especially a male

[and](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/black?s=t):

> *black* noun 21.b. *Often Offensive.* African-American.

No such usage notes are attached to the adjectival uses.

I'm guessing that transgender people would prefer to be called "transgender people" (or "people who are transgender") rather than "transgenders".

Comment: I think the warning should be made stronger.  Using "transgenders" as a noun is offensive and even though understandable, should not be done.